# LibJitsi: Video PlayBack

Tags: video-streaming, rtp, jitsi

I am using libjitsi to create a application as part of my assignment to send and receive media.I am not able to understand how can i playback the received video stream.I have tried the sample codes of AVTransmit2 and AVReceive2 and only audio is played back!
Similar question has been asked previously on other forums and someone has hinted towards taking hint from Jitsi API and its source code.I am trying that too , but it is taking a lot of time. 
Does anyone have a clear idea of Jitsi/libjitsi API or proper documentation on how to do basic stuff like displaying a video from rtp stream ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to play back video. If you look in the API, there is a package for Swing components (org.jitsi.util.swing). You'll need code like this:

https://github.com/Metaswitch/libjitsi/blob/master/src/org/jitsi/examples/PacketPlayer/PlayRTP.java

And you'll need to render it into an org.jitsi.util.swing.VideoContainer. The listener in the above example detects when video starts coming in and puts that video inside of the constructor of the VideoContainer, which is just a special type of JPanel.